# How to add an amount of years to all dates stored as String format stored in a mongo collection

Tags: mongodb

For a college project i have imported a household energy consumption dataset on my MongoDB.

dataset:https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/individual+household+electric+power+consumption

For my purposes, I need to split each sub-metering while still maintaining the date and time. But also since this dataset is from 2006 i'd like to add 8 years to the date so i have a date closer to now.

The approach i have been following is to create a view for each sub metering.

Structure of my document :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceec64e871bf4fa89a7f4f3"),
    "Date" : "16/12/2006",
    "Time" : "17:24:00",
    "Global_active_power" : 4.216,
    "Global_reactive_power" : 0.418,
    "Voltage" : 234.84,
    "Global_intensity" : 18.4,
    "Sub_metering_1" : 0.0,
    "Sub_metering_2" : 1.0,
    "Sub_metering_3" : 17.0
}
```

And i use the following to create the views :

```
db.createView("sub_metering1","sensor",[{$project: {"_id":"$_id","datetime":{ $dateFromString:{ dateString: {$concat:[ "$Date"," ","$Time"]},format:"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" }},"metering":"$Sub_metering_1"}}])
```

The views work fine, but i simply can't figure out how to add the 8 years to the original date. I tried to do a find and then a forEach to update, but the documents werent updated, it also took too long to execute.

The dataset starts in 2006 and ends in 2010, i wanted the dates to be pushed 8 years so it started in 2014 and ended in 2018.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just wanted to say that to format code you can use 4 spaces of indentation (highlight the code + ctrl-K) or place it between sets of triple backticks (```)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

First i retrieved all the dates with 8 added years. And then iterated over it with a for each loop to add a new field to each document.

Used the $add operation on top of the $dateFromString operation to add the years to my date value, the time had to be added in milliseconds though, which gave me: 8*365*24*60*60000 for 8 years.

mongo docs about $add operation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/

Please find my script below:

```
 var datetime=db.sensor.aggregate([
        {$project:{ "_id":"$_id", "datetime": { $add:[
            { $dateFromString:{ dateString: {$concat:[ "$Date"," ","$Time"]},format:"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" }}
            ,8*365*24*60*60000    
            ]}}}
    ])

    datetime.forEach(function(doc){
            db.sensor.updateMany({_id:doc._id},{$set: {datetime:doc.datetime}})
        })
```